# 03/20/11 11:24 AM(MONTH/DATE/YEAR HOUR:MIN)

Tags: iphone

I am using the below code:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
    NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    [dateFormatter release];
```

This will not give me this format 03/20/11 11:24 AM(MONTH/DATE/YEAR HOUR:MIN), if i convert system date and time so the converted string should have such type of information 03/20/11 11:24 AM(MONTH/DATE/YEAR HOUR:MIN).? What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this and u will get the format

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm"];
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
[formatter release];
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

you should set the date format as,

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm a"];
```